# How to restrict users for Org Unit selection.?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

During installation of app from chrome store, google allows user to select domain or org unit within domain. I want to allow users to install app for domain not for org unit .How to restrict users from org unit selection.?  is it possible ? if yes then how to do it.?

Comment: can anyone tell me atleast whether it is possible or not.?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can enforce that your app is always installed for entire domain and not for an OU.